# How to remove duplicate npm packages if root has a different major version than dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

My dependency tree looks like the following:

```
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@2.0.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@2.0.19
│ ├─┬ react-component-lib@1.10.16
├─┬ react-component-lib@2.0.9
```

I don't want the `react-component-lib` getting pulled in so many times when I deploy my production artifact. We are using the latest version of npm and webpack to bundle our assets. We have tried using `npm prune` and `npm dedupe`and nothing. We have currently concluded that this is occurring because the root project has version 2 while the dependencies have version 1 so dedupe cant flatten the structure. Any ideas how we can solve this problem?

Comment: Note we are using `^` for our dependencies in the package.json.

Answer (score 1):

fastest way is 
  - re-edit the package.json file ,
  -  delete node_modules folder and 
  - run npm install